# where do I push messages in the constructor? (Angular, Observables, Subject)

Tags: angular, observable, subject

I have a MessagesService, where i can sendMessage and getMessage:

```
export class MessagesService {

  constructor() { }

  private subject = new Subject<any>();

  sendMessage(message: string): void {
    this.subject.next({ text: message });
  }

  clearMessages(): void {
    this.subject.next();
  }

  getMessage(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }

}
```

In the MessagesComponent i call the getMessage method:

```
export class MessagesComponent implements OnInit {
  message: any = {};
  subscription: Subscription;


  constructor(public messagesService: MessagesService) {
    this.subscription = this.messagesService.getMessage().subscribe(message => { this.message = message; });
  }
```

And also in its template:

```
  {{message?.text}}
```

Now in another component, where I use sendMessage (in the .ts file) and put a string in it, I call in its template

Now my question:
is it correct to put this into the brackets of the constructer of this file:

```
constructor(private heroService: HeroService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private enemyService: EnemyService,
  public messagesService: MessagesService) {

  this.subscription = this.messagesService.getMessage().subscribe(message => {
    if (message) {
      this.messages.push(message);
    } else {
      // clear messages when empty message received
      this.messages = [];
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is what we call life cycle hooks in Angular. It's ok to add your subscription in your constructor or in 'ngOnInit' to ensure that the component is already initialized.

Comment: Okay got it. Do you see any missings in my code why it doesnt work?

Comment: In your template I think it's best to just use {{ message.text }}.
In this part this.subscription = this.messagesService.getMessage().subscribe(message => {
    if (message) {
      this.messages.push(message);
    } else {
      // clear messages when empty message received
      this.messages = [];
    }
  });
You can remove the 'if' statement and just push the message. You will only receive a blank message when you call 'clearMessages' using your service. I guess one of the reasons why it's not working I don't see you used 'sendMessage' in your service to call this.subject.next

Comment: Let me know if it works already when invoking the function 'sendMessage' in your service. That's the part where it emits the value. Maybe somewhere in your component, you can call 'this.messageService.sendMessage('hello')'. If by default you want to emit a value initially you can also use BehaviorSubject instead of Subject. BehaviorSubject needs an initial value